# how to increase accuracy of neural network in land marks detection and recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

i am working on  land marks detection and to football fields from camera

so i build a neural network but i get a very low accuracy and high loss

x data is football matches images taken from camera

y data is coordinates of 29 land marks across the field

example :
[image]

link for the dataset:

[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DKLJ4vRgsdHAnRhUZPcCPCs1Jkc7vUBP?usp=sharing)

x shape (565, 320, 320, 3)

y shape (565, 29, 2)

every land mark have a two values x,y and land marks that is not in the image take -1

example :

```
y[0]=array([[ 72., 133.],[ 39., 148.],[122., 154.],
[  3., 163.],
[ 33., 166.],
[ -1.,  -1.],
[ -1.,  -1.],......])
```

NOTE:

i did normalize for( x => /255  , y => /320) to make the data between 0-1 for x and (-1,0-1) for y

model :

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((320,320,3))
l = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(5,5),padding='same')(input)
l=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(l)
l = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(5,5),padding='same')(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(l)
l = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(5,5),padding='same')(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='tanh')(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='tanh')(l)
l=tf.keras.layers.Dense(29*2,activation='tanh')(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model does not really seem well suited to detect objects. For object detection, a more complex architecture is required. You may look at the YOLO object detector, which is a very popular object detection model. In this repository, there is a rather easy to use and easy to retrain implementation of YOLOv3 available:
https://github.com/YunYang1994/TensorFlow2.0-Examples

There are many reasons, why your model will not perform well for object detection. One reason is, that you seem to always predict exactly 29 landmarks, even if there are less objects in the image. Additionally, it is quite hard for the network to determine, which landmark to place at which position in your output, since your output does not preserve the structure of the image and presents the final landmark predictions in an unordered way. This introduces the problem of how to train the model, since you need to assign a landmark to a specific network output to train it. Models like YOLO work differently, as they predict if there is an object at many, regularly spaced, positions in the image, in combination with a score that tells you, how confident a detection is. This solves the problems I just described and should be a good output for your model.

If you do not want to use another repository and instead want to create a new model from scratch, a simple approach might look like this: Do not use dense layers at the end of the model. Instead, use convolutional layers, and additionally use smaller strides in the earlier layers. If you, for example, only use strides of (2, 2) and only use strides two times, this should give you (at some stage in your network) convolutional layers with a shape of (90, 90, n), with n being the number of filters in the convolutional layer. Now you could just set n=1, which basically gives you a result that gives you a 90x90 array of values, that are evenly spread over your image. Then you could train the model, to use these evenly spaced values to predict the probability of an object being at the current location, so that a value of over 0.5 will mean that an object was detected at the corresponding position.

Comment: thank you so much , it seems very nice way i will try and tell you the result

Comment: but i think when i use strides two times with (2,2) i get 80,80 not 90,90 , ( 320->160->80) or i am wrong ??

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with it. Yes, (80, 80) is correct, it seems like I just divided incorrectly in my head.

Comment: i have a question bro , now i have 30 class ( 1 for background and 29 for landmarks ) , my data is imbalanced there are many samples of background and a very low samples for landmarks in every image , this makes my cnn model loss to high but in testing on land marks is not good , do you have any idea ?

Comment: i searched and i found concept of class weights but this concept works only on 2d output not 3d in my case

Comment: I do not quite understand how you set up your models output. Do you have a convolutional layer with 30 feature maps per position, to indicate which landmarks are at this position? This will most likely not work well. Just to clarify: Do the landmarks have any order? So can landmark 3 and landmark 15 be interchanged easily? If this is the case, the network will not know which neuron to activate the most. This is why my idea was to predict only a single value per grid position, which only indicates whether there is a landmark at the position or not.

Comment: In this way, you can just predict, at which positions in the image there are landmarks, and then you can extract them and enumerate them how you like afterwards.

Comment: Ah it looks like I missunderstood your dataset. If there are 30 different classes, then your approach will be correct, but then it is just very hard for the network to correctly learn all of the different types of landmarks from just 565 images. But still, you should at least be able to achieve some success with your approach, so there still seems to be a problem if the approach performs very badly. Your idea with the class weights is good, this would probably work in the following way:

Comment: Your loss function for the network should be the cross entropy (between every 30-dimensional output vector in your prediction grid and the ground truth one-hot encoded vectors indicating the real label). If you want to incorporate class weights into this, you just take the individual cross-entropies at all 6400 positions and then you multiply the resulting 80*80 matrix containing all the individual losses by a discount factor (e.g. 0.01) at every index that is supposed to predict the label "background". Afterwards you sum over all values to get the complete loss value for your network.

Comment: Just as a further note: If you have such a small dataset, using pretrained networks is usually the way to go, since this makes it easier for the network to learn from a small number of samples. I do not quite know which network would work for this that well, but maybe you find something useful that can somehow be altered to fit your purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237823/discussion-between-marc-felix-and-salo7ty).

Comment: okay bro i sent message in disscussion

Comment: i have no words for you bro , thanks you for your helping , thank you so much 

https://github.com/saleh1312/python/blob/master/football_landMarks_detection.ipynb

this is the final code , please look at it

Comment: You're welcome, great that it worked!

Comment: you are so helpful and amazing thank you so much , i have another question if you dont mind , now after i trained my model , it makes good accuracy on training set , but when i test it in another images out of the dataset it does not make good result i think because the overfitting and the low data that i have , i tried to augment the data by blurring every image but still the model overfit , do you have any advise on data augmentation or model architecture that maybe make my model better in test data , thank you so much

Comment: There are different techniques to improve the generalization ability of neural networks. Data augmentation should definitely be helpful, even though I am not sure if blurring is the way to go in your case. Since I am no expert in this, I googled quickly and saw that blurring is mostly used for image classification tasks, so I am not quite sure whether it is helpful here (if it works for you then keep doing it though!). Other data augmentation techniques especially involve cropping and rotating the image, but if you want to use these techniques then you should do it with care, since

Comment: football images usually all look quite similar, so an image that is rotated by 90° or an image that is cropped to only show a small portion of the field probably makes not that much sense.

Comment: Since you use batch normalization (which is good), many of the classical regularization techniques do not make sense (like L2 regularization or dropout). But early stopping could definitely help. This basically means that you do not train your network on your training set until the error stops decreasing, but instead you stop earlier and hope that the network did not just memorize your training set yet. Usually, you would find the right stopping point by keeping a third set of images which you do not use for training but just use to check when the performance of the model gets worse.

Comment: The most helpful thing usually is using a pretrained network though. There are many networks out there that are for example pretrained to do classification on the imagenet data set, and you can just retrain the model to work for your task. The problem here is, that most of these networks will not have the correct structure for your problem, since the last convolutional layers of a network like for example VGG16 only have very few neurons and are thus not fine-grained enough for your pixelwise labeling task. You might be able to find a good (smaller) pretrained network somewhere online though.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is using a different network structure. Your structure so far is rather simple and there are more complex structures out there that for example do pixlewise labeling tasks with structures that incorporate local as well as more global cues by using structures that connect early layers with upscaled later layers in the network. If you want to give this a go, try searching for something like "feature pyramid network", some of these networks might be (with some minor changes) very well applicable for your problem and there are pretrained versions of them out there.

Comment: If you are using a pretrained network, then definitely keep early stoppign in mind, since the more complex networks will probably be very well capable of memorizing your taining set and will not generalize well if you train them too long.